# How To change path in FIleStream.Name to system Temp folder path

Tags: vb.net

I can successfully retrieve a file from a database, but it is directly going in my project's Debug folder. I want to change the path to system's Temp folder please see below code:

```
Dim pth as String = Path.GetTempPath
Dim FStream As New FileStream(fgdoc.Rows(I).Cells(6).Value.ToString, FileMOde.Create, FileAccess.Write)
FStream.Write(tempfile, 0, tempfile.Length)
FStream.Close()
```

`tempfile` is a byte datatype to take the file from database in byte format.

Where should I put "pth" to change the default path to system's temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `fgdoc.Rows(I).Cells(6).Value.ToString` returns the filename with no path information, you can use `IO.Path.Combine` to add the path to the Temp folder.

```
Dim pth As String = Path.GetTempPath
Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(pth, fgdoc.Rows(I).Cells(6).Value.ToString)
Dim FStream As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
FStream.Write(tempfile, 0, tempfile.Length)
FStream.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you So much for help, It Worked